# Vimeo froogaloop

Tags: javascript, vimeo

Very much a newbie here, but I'm trying to use [this idea](https://codepen.io/ilake/pen/EVyWEe) to disable forward seeking in Vimeo clips embedded on a Wordpress site

To my functions.php I've added

```
function frogaloop_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('snippet', 'https://siteurl/wp-content/themes/themename/js/snippet.js');
    wp_register_script('frogaloop','https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js');
    }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'frogaloop_scripts' );
```

On a page with an embedded video, I've got

```
<iframe id="video1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/xxxxx?api=1&player_id=video1" width="630" height="354" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Where 'video1' matches the iframe label in the codepen example.

When I load the page source, I can't even see frogaloop being listed, so I'm not sure the enqueuing is even happening...

Where am I going wrong with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so I'm not sure the enqueuing is even happening

No, it's not, because you only registered the scripts, but never enqueued them — which should be done using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

Also, you should make `frogaloop` as a dependency for your `snippet.js` script. Hence, register the `frogaloop` script before your `snippet.js` script.

```php
// Register the scripts.
wp_register_script( 'frogaloop', 'https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js', array(), null );
// The third parameter is the script dependencies.
wp_register_script( 'snippet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/snippet.js', array( 'frogaloop' ) );

// Then enqueue them. But you just need to call:
wp_enqueue_script( 'snippet' );
// because frogaloop will also be enqueued because it's a dependency for your
// snippet.js script.
```

Now that should work.

Comment: Thank you, all working now !

Comment: You're welcome! And BTW, the Froogaloop script handle/ID should be `froogaloop` and not `frogaloop`.. =)